# Connect PowerApps to Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird, powerapps, data-gateway

I want to connect PowerApps to my local Firebird SQL server, how do I go about it?

I want to make a Pricelist App that connects to a local Firebird SQL server. Excel only permits up to 15,000 items. I have 25,000 items. Also, I'd like for it to be updated every time someone edits the local database.

Answer (score 2):

PowerApps do support many data sources, but firebird SQL isn't supported at this time. Consider creating a new issue on the [PowerApps Ideas Board](https://aka.ms/powerapps-ideas) to have the product team investigate it.

Comment: The link doesn't answer the question, the paragraph above it does (it says that this is not currently supported, which is the answer). The link is an additional information that may help the OP.

Answer (score 1):

In your shoes, I'd try spinning up a SQL Server (express edition?) and creating a connection to the firebird database as a linked server.  Then you'll need to create a ssis package or stored procedure for moving data from the firebird server into the SQL server.  Adjust the refresh timing to your liking.

This may seem like a PITA but it beats waiting for Microsoft to support other DBs.
Hope it helps,