# Connect Powerapps to Firebird SQL

Tags: firebird, powerapps

Microsoft just release on-premise SQL support for PowerApps. How do I connect my local Firebird SQL to PowerApps?

Comment: As far as I can tell you can only connect to SQL Server this way.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel How do I connect? I know it's the only way but how do I connect?

Comment: You can't connect to Firebird , because as far as I can tell, only Microsoft SQL Server is supported. Read the docs to see how you can connect to that.

Comment: Responded here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37916645/connect-powerapps-to-firebird/45922660#45922660